# AWS CDK. Aurora + fargate service

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-fargate, amazon-aurora

I am trying to create a Fargate Service that connects to an Aurora Postgres DB through the CDK, but I am unable. I get an error connection. This should be pretty straightforward though. Does anybody have any resources?

```js
export class myStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";

        const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "myVpc");

        const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "myCluster", {
            vpc: vpc
        });

        const databaseAdminSecret = new Secret(this, 'myCredentialsSecret', {
            secretName: 'database-secret',
            description: 'Database auto-generated user password',
            generateSecretString: {
                secretStringTemplate: JSON.stringify({username: 'boss'}),
                generateStringKey: 'password',
                passwordLength: 30,
                excludeCharacters: "\"@/\\",
                excludePunctuation: true,
            }
        });

        const database = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, 'myDatabase', {
            engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres({
                version: rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_14_5
            }),
            credentials: rds.Credentials.fromSecret(databaseAdminSecret),
            instanceProps: {
                vpc,
            },
            defaultDatabaseName: DATABASE_NAME,
            port: 5432,
        });


        // Create a load-balanced Fargate service and make it public
        const service = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, "myService", {
            cluster: cluster, // Required
            taskImageOptions: {
                image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('my-custom-image'),
                environment: {

                    DB_URL: `jdbc:postgresql://${database.clusterEndpoint.socketAddress}/${DATABASE_NAME}`,
                    DB_USERNAME: databaseAdminSecret.secretValueFromJson('username').unsafeUnwrap().toString(),
                    DB_PASSWORD: databaseAdminSecret.secretValueFromJson('password').unsafeUnwrap().toString(),

                },
            },
        });

        // Allow the service to connect to the database
        database.connections.allowDefaultPortFrom(service.service);
    }
}
```

When I spin up this stack with `cdk deploy` my Fargate service ends up dying because "Connection was refused".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,